# Set results of a query in the same row

Tags: mysql

I have this table called r_paper_attribute, made like this.

```
paper_id  attribute_id  string_value    date_value
1               1       foo
1               2                       2023-01-01
1               3       bar
1               4                       2023-02-03
2               1       foo
2               2                       2023-02-01
2               3       bar
```

I would like to know if it possible in MySQL to group the results on the same row maintaining the order of the columns, I've tried to make a select with GROUP_CONCAT function, but I can't really accomplish what I want.

The result should be something like this:

`1,foo,2023-01-01,bar,2023-02-03`

is it possible?

Comment: Have you already tried anything to solve this problem? Got stuck somewhere?

Comment: @lemon I've tried to do this: SELECT r.paper_id, GROUP_CONCAT(r.string_value SEPARATOR ","),  GROUP_CONCAT(r.date_valueSEPARATOR ",")  FROM r_paper_attribute r GROUP BY r.paper_id. This query doesn't maintain column order.

Comment: You could try getting inspiration with the approach presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns), or look online for pivoting in mysql. You should find a way to unwrap this problem easily.

Comment: Try ``SELECT r.paper_id
  , GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(',',r.string_value,r.date_value ) 
     SEPARATOR ",")
FROM r_paper_attribute r GROUP BY r.paper_id``